# Importing a 3d object file (.obj) using VTK and C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

Recently I am working on a project which involves working on 3D Object files. I have to used VTK and C++ for the code. I used the code available from tutorials of VTK for importing a 3d Object File, but after building the solution I am not able to open the ReadObj.exe file.

Following is the code:-

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkOBJReader.h>

#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkCamera.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkNamedColors.h>

#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Parse command line arguments
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "Filename(.obj) e.g trumpet.obj " << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::string filename = "Data/elephanm.obj";
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader> reader =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
  reader->Update();

  // Visualize
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkNamedColors> colors =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkNamedColors>::New();
  vtkColor3d backgroundColor = colors->GetColor3d("SpringGreen");
  vtkColor3d actorColor      = colors->GetColor3d("HoneyDew");

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);
  actor->GetProperty()->SetDiffuseColor(actorColor.GetData());

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  renderer->AddActor(actor);
  renderer->SetBackground(backgroundColor.GetData());
  renderer->ResetCamera();
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Azimuth(30);
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Elevation(30);
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Dolly(1.5);
  renderer->ResetCameraClippingRange();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

  renderWindow->SetSize(640, 480);
  renderWindow->Render();

  renderWindowInteractor->Start();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also, Build is successful in Visual Studio and ReadObj.exe gets created. But the exe file does not open and does not show the result

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by: "The file does not open". How do you call your code? What is the error you have (if any)? You need to specify the file to open when you call your code. In Visual Studio, this will be an argument in the debugging section. When you run it in the console, you would call it like this: `> ReadObj.exe yourfile.obj`

Comment: @fern17Hi, it is showing me a system error dialogue box. Some .dll missing errors.

Comment: we need to see the errors to understand what is the problem. Do you have defined the path to VTK in your system (PATH environment variable?)

Comment: @fern17yes I have defined the path to VTK in my system.

Comment: @fern17Error reads out:- The code execution cannot proceed because vtkIOGeometry-8.2.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

Comment: I don't know how you have installed VTK (or compiled), but that means that you are missing the DLLs in the PATH. Please double check that the path were the DLL is located is indeed in the PATH environment variable. You can use this software: https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/ to see what are the dependencies you are missing in runtime (I guess all the VTK dlls)